# how do i removing last input if its a mathematical symbols on a calculator

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i want to remove the last input if its a mathematical symbols on a calculator meaning 2+2+= 4 rather than NaN

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-germain-rru4e?file=/script.js that's the code

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you mean when you type 4 into the input, the checkbox should be hidden?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code in your question, so that your question makes sense when the link is (inevitably) 404 in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove trailing operators in line 36

Try replacing

```
let screenValue = screen.value.split(" ");
```

with

```
let screenValue = screen.value.replace(/[-+x÷]$/,'').split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically in these cases, I create a tree data structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and process it. In your case, however, it can be a simple stack (in a javascript array) that can be used to solve this reliably.

```
|Var1|
------
|op  |
------
|var2|
------
|op. |
------
|Var3|
------
```

When you process this stack you can skip processing any operation that does not have a variable that follows it.